# Is there a Linux command that can indicate if the mobo is functional to charge a battery or not?

Tags: command, hardware, laptop, battery

I have a Toshiba Satellite **L845-SP4146KL** - it currently has Linux Ubuntu 22.04 installed.
The original battery passed away, I tried to buy a compatible/equivalent battery - but it is **not** certified. The point is, the tested battery to be buy it does not charge completely. Practically nothing. 30 minutes can passed and the battery does not pass the 5%.

According to the seller, it is possible that the motherboard is damaged specifically for this function, causing it to be unable to charge the battery. The seller does not have a certified battery to test it. Currently, the laptop functions properly when connected directly to the electrical power source.

Therefore,

**Question**

- Is there a Linux command that can indicate if the mobo is functional to charge a battery or not?

Comment: "only charges a battery halfway" is more than a surprising malfunction. I'd guess the vendor is trying to be let off the hook. And, no, why would a laptop have a sensor for that? A laptop battery charger just works, some are actually configurable, but such malfunctionality would be unusual enough for not be something to be neccessary to be detectable by software

Comment: Can you find out which fuel gauge IC is used in the system? The driver probably shows up in the `dmesg`, but you may also find some information by using your favorite search engine. Or do you have the kernel config? Once you have it, check whether it needs some kind of reset after replacing the battery. Next, you can access it via I2C to read out everything including charging current (if this isn't shown in some `/sys/class/whatever`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you ever tried to estimate the remaining capacity of a LiIon pack using nothing but the voltage, you know why fuel gauges like bq24... are integrated, which needs to measure the current from/to the battery anyhow.

Comment: @Philippos exactly, but all that charge counting and voltage detection could tell you is that "we topped up that battery as far as it's safe to do. Now at x% the nominal capacity." Which Manuel already knows!

Comment: Thanks for the friendly replies - Should I test yes or yes with a certificated battery? ... I would be happy if the problem is with the battery not certificated itself. Of course, the certificated is more expensive, it has a cost of US$60 here in my country, and the not certificated the half of the price.

Comment: *"the motherboard is damaged specifically for this function, causing it to be unable to charge the battery"* this sounds extremely unlikely. *"a certificated battery"* would be a much better idea. There are way too many fake batteries  on the market.